# Add a settings page for bitbucket add-on

Tags: javascript, jquery, bitbucket-server

I have created an add-on for Atlassian Bitbucket Server. I would like the add-on to be enabled or disabled at the repository level.

So I was able to add a web-item at the ADD-ONs section of Settings page of a repository. Now, how do I add my enable/disable radio buttons or a toggle button on the right side screen?

Right now, clicking on web-item takes me to a servlet and renders a velocity template on a different page. But for other add-ons I have noticed that, the settings page is rendered on the same page unlike my case.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out myself. My assumption that, the settings page is rendered on the same page is not true. The settings page is appeared as a new page but that just looks like the previous page.

To make the new page look consistent, use page decorators in the velocity template or in my case, I have used a soy template.

Check this repository to understand how to add various page decorators for the soy templates. : https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bitbucket-example-plugin

Thanks,
Kaushik